# jquery mobile pageinit not firing after changepage event

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to navigate to a different .html page using

I have got two HTML Pages namely one.html and second.htmml

On click of  button button under one.html , i am calling second.html as shown below

```
function callPage () {
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', 'second.html', {
        transition: 'slide',
        changeHash: false,
        reverse: true,
        showLoadMsg: true
    });
  }
```

**Second.html**

```
 $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#homedeliverypage", function( event )
    {
    alert('Alert not getting called');
    });
      </script>
      </head>
      <body >
        <div data-role="page" id="homedeliverypage">
        </div>div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The Pageinit event is never getting called

However, if I do window.location.href = "second.html" then everything fires accordingly.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: dont put $(document).on("pageinit".... in the header... try putting it in the body of the script?

Comment: Thnak you very much .